# AngularJs mfb-directive floating buttons

Tags: html, angularjs, floating-action-button

I am trying to understand angularJs implementation with floating button dynamically (mfb-directive). While trying to understand there are couple issues, which I am not able to understand

**Issue 1:**

Not able to form menu with single iteration of **ng-repeat**
While trying to populate 4 buttons dynamically from JSON, (ButtonMenu  + 3 Buttons), I need to run **ng-repeat** twice for forming the menu.

```
  <nav ng-if="$first" mfb-menu position="bl" effect="zoomin" label="{{menu.name}}" ng-repeat="menu in menus">
  <a ng-if="!$first" mfb-button icon="{{menu.name}}" label="{{menu.name}}" ng-repeat="menu in menus"></a>
</nav>
```

Trying to achieve this with single iteration of menus, Did try all know options, but none worked.

Issue 2:
Assigning click action for buttons

I am trying to assign actions to each button click start from MFB-menu button to other required buttons with data-ng-click with menu.id as an argument to identify and process the clicked button. When I click, mfb menu it works as expected, but if I click on mfb-button. It sends 2 events, 1st event is event assigned to the button and the 2nd event is event assigned for mfb-menu

Attached plunker for refernece: [Plunker ref](https://plnkr.co/edit/6vA3aK8iYWypKR2cYW54?p=preview)

Request some guidance

Answer (score 0):

I think for ng-repeat you can make use of conditional attribute, I see only difference is your attributes getting changes ex.

```
 ng-attr-position="{{$index < 3 ? 'b1' : undefined}}"
```

that way you only have to use only single ng-repeat.

Comment: During first instance : it is " mfb-menu position="bl" and after that it is  mfb-button

Comment: Yeah you can change attributes, based on your condition.

Comment: is it possible for you show a plunk ? There are 2 atributes that needs change **nav** / *a** and mfb-button / mfb-menu